# How can I break nasted for loop in Paskal without using goto statement?

Tags: loops, for-loop, break

```
    procedure obrada(a,b:matrica; m,n,m1,n1:integer);
    var i,j:integer; uslov:boolean;
    begin
     if (m<>n1) and (n<>m1) then writeln('Nema transponovanja.')
     else
     begin
     uslov:=true;
     for i:=1 to m do
      for j:=1 to n do
       if (a[i,j]<>b[j,i]) then
       begin
            uslov:=false;//What should I write here to go directly on line 
                           'writeln('Can not be obtained');' and stop checking this 
                            matrix when this codition is true?
       end;
     if uslov then writeln('The first matrix can not be obtained by transposing other ')
     else writeln('Can not be obtained');
     end;
    end;
```

Please read a comment in this code block and answer for that question if you know some solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use `Break;`

More info here: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/break.html

Comment: No, no. Break won't help, because the break statement will stop the execution of the innermost loop and start executing the next line of code after the block and that is for loop again...

Comment: @dusica - Then you need one more Break for the second loop.